# What does "expected unqualified id before 'if'" mean?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

> I am not getting why this is not working. I was researching on fixes and they say to add that "if" block in the void loop. Well, that was always in the void loop. Can you tell me the meaning and fix? Also, if there are more errors, please notify me so I can fix it. My code can be a little disorganized. 
>   My code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd (7,8,9,10,11,12);

int pinDHT11 = 2;
SimpleDHT11 dht11;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
lcd.begin(16,2);
}

void loop() {
}
   if (dht11.read(pinDHT11, &temperature, &humidity,data))
    Serial.print("Read DHT11 failed");
    return;

  byte temperature = 0;
  byte humidity = 0;
  byte data[40] = {0};
  if(dht11.read (pinDHT11, &temperature, &humidity, data)) 
    return;
  Serial.print("Read DHT11 failed");



  Serial.println("=================================");
  Serial.println("Sample DHT11...");

  // read with raw sample data.
  byte temperature = 0;
  byte humidity = 0;
  byte data[40] = {0};


  }

  Serial.print("Sample RAW Bits: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    Serial.print((int)data[i]);
    if (i > 0 && ((i + 1) % 4) == 0) {
      Serial.print(' ');
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Sample OK: ");

  Serial.print((int)temperature); Serial.print("*C,");
  Serial.print((int)humidity); Serial.println("%");

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print((int)temperature);
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd,print((int)humidity);

  // DHT11 sampling rate is 1HZ.
  delay(1000);
```

Comment: This might be better suited on code review rather than stack.  You have a bracket ending the void loop immediately after the one that opens it.  You also will need brackets around statements in that first if block.  Otherwise, return will be called every time.  And a closing bracket at the end.  Have fun with the Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

Your void loop is empty.

```
void loop() {
}
```

The error message is caused because you may not have code outside of functions. The only thing that is allowed outside functions are declarations.

There is a `}` without a matching `{`.

You also have two unconditional return statements.

`,` instead of `.`

```
lcd,print((int)humidity);
```